# Finding value of infinite sum arising from hitting time in Markov Chain

Tags: sequences-and-series, markov-chains

I am given a two-state Markov chain with transition matrix

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1-p & p \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$

and am asked to calculate the mean time of hitting state $2$ given that the chain starts at state $1$. Let $X_i$ be a R.V. which represents the state at time $i$, so $X_0 = 1$. Also, I let $F_n(x,y)$ be the probability that state $y$ is reached for the first time after $n$ steps if we start with state $x$.

I showed that $F_n(2, 1) = (1-p)^{n-1}p$ using the time invariance property of Markov Chains and recursion. Now I am asked to find the mean time of hitting state $2$ which by the definition of expectation I think should be

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(1-p)^{n-1}p.
$$

However, I can't see how to find the sum of this series since it has an $n$ term that's growing linearly, but presumably the $(1-p)^{n-1}$ is decreasing as a power so the terms should go to $0$ sufficiently fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generating function approach. Say that:

$$
F(x) = p\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(1-p)^{n-1}x^{n-1}
$$

Note that I changed the limit from $n = 1$ to $n = 0$ and confirm this is valid. This makes for an easier application of the geometric series later. Then we have $F(1)$ as your wanted expected value ($xF(x)$ is the G.F. for the terms of your sum). Then, integrating both sides and rearranging:

$$\int F(x)dx = \frac{p}{1-p}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1-p)^{n}x^n$$

Now we can use the formula for the geometric series:

$$\int F(x)dx = \frac{p}{1-p}\cdot \frac{1}{1-(1-p)x}$$

And we can differentiate again to get back $F$ (remember $\frac{d}{dx}(1-cx)^{-1} = c(1 - cx)^{-2}$):

$$F(x) =\frac{p}{((1-p)x - 1)^2}$$

Now substitute $F(1)$ to find expected value $\frac{1}{p}$.

---

The crux of the above answer is to use integration to solve $\sum nc^n$. We  get rid of the factor $n$ by using $\int x^{n-1}dx = \frac{1}{n}x^n$.

Comment: Thank you for this – I'm not sure I would've seen this trick on my own. One small correction: I think the limit of your sum should start with $n=1$ as it is in my question. That should change the numerator of the formula after using the geometric series sum, but strangely enough, I get the same value for $F(x)$ after taking a derivative.

Comment: My expression for $\int F(x)\, dx$  is $$ \int F(x)\, dx = \frac{px}{1-(1-p)x}. $$ To be sure, I checked with WolframAlpha and verified that it has the same result for both our derivatives, even though the inputs are different as far as I can tell: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+(p%2F(1-p))+*+((1)%2F(1-(1-p)x)) vs. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of++(px)+%2F+(1-(1-p)x)

Comment: @quiet I intentionally changed the limit of the sum from $n = 1$ to $n = 0$ to simplify manually differentiating by removing the $x$ from the numerator and use the simpler formula for the geometric series. Note that this is valid because when $n = 0$ the body of the sum is also $0$. We have to be careful not to divide by zero, so it's not valid when $p = 0$ or $x = 0$ but we don't care about those values anyway. The fact that you get the same derivative is correct - after all it's the same sum. I should have mentioned this little trick though.